# Can't enter SQL commands phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using Debian(jessie). I created a database(Cars) using phpMyAdmin's Create database function. I'm following along a book "The Joy of php". After the table is created the author wants to create a table (INVENTORY) using SQL commands. Well, phpMyAdmin will not let me enter any text in the SQL query text area. I created the table using the Create table function(buttons). If I click on the INVENTORY table in the left window-pane or the tab above I get the following error message:

```
    Error

    SELECT 'prefs' FROM 'phpmyadmin' . 'pma__table_uiprefs' WHERE 'username' = 'jeff' AND           'db_name' = 'Cars' AND 'table_name' = 'INVENTORY'

    MySQL said:

    #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__table_uiprefs'
    doesn't exist
```

If I click on columns under INVENTORY or the Structure tab above I can view the table and columns. Also when I click on the SQL tab I can view the table columns in the right-hand pane and the number 1 appears in the SQL command text field. If more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks,
Jeff

================================================================================

OK, I got rid of all the error messages.  I was finally able to import create_tables.sql.gz into phpMyAdmin by deleting the phpmyadmin database, extracting create_tables.sql.gz to a temporary directory and then importing create_tables.sql into phpMyAdmin.  Happily I no longer receive error messages.  Unfortunatly I still cannot enter any text in the SQL text-area.  I did create an sql file to import and create a database and table.  This worked flawlessly.  So I still maintain there is a bug here.

I've submitted a bug report at Source Forge but all I have gotten from them is that my version is outdated.  I'm using the version aptitude installs (below are the details).  I update aptitude every day.  The version I have on Windows is older and yet it doesn't seem to be outdated to the point of not working.  Thanks for reading.

Database Server:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.35-2 - (Debian)
Protocol version: 10
User: jeff@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web Server:
Apache/2.4.7 (Debian)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.35
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

phpMyAdmin:
Version information: 4.1.9deb1

Answer (score 0):

That table name is part of the [phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage), which is used to give you access to things like bookmarked queries, or in the case of the `pma__table_uiprefs` table, sorting and column order for customized display when browsing.

However, this error message is quite strange because if phpMyAdmin can't find the tables, usually a warning message is displayed on the main page like

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

Do you see a message like that towards the bottom of the main page? What phpMyAdmin version do you have? Is there a `phpmyadmin` database in your MySQL instance, and if so, does it contain a table named something like `pma__table_uiprefs`?

To disable the problem, try editing your `config.inc.php` and commenting out the line that starts with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']`. Your table name may vary, but after you comment it out it should appear something like `// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';` -- then close your browser and try again. That should completely bypass the entire phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage system.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by reconfiguring phpmyadmin and providing a root access in order to update the phpmyadmin database and config files.

```
dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Output:

```
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
Replacing config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version
granting access to database phpmyadmin for phpmyadmin@localhost: already exists.
creating database phpmyadmin: already exists.
populating database via sql...  done.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
apache2_invoke phpmyadmin: already enabled
```

Answer (score -1):

but why  `phpmyadmin` . `pma__table_uiprefs`   ?

```
SELECT 'prefs' FROM  'pma__table_uiprefs' WHERE 'username' = 'jeff' AND 'db_name' = 'Cars' AND 'table_name' = 'INVENTORY';
```

Comment: Well, phpMyAdmin will not let me enter any text in the SQL query text area.  The code above is an ERROR MESSAGE generated by phpMyAdmin

Comment: Did you logged in as administrator?

Comment: I have logged in as root and no luck.  The table Cars was created as user jeff (me) so jeff should be able to enter SQL commands.  I'm wondering if it is a bug in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The error << Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__table_uiprefs' doesn't exist >> means that table doesn't existe,you must misspelled table name.

Comment: user3219446, I didn't **misspell** anything. I didn't **spell** anything.  **I can't input any text in the SQL text-box area!**

Comment: Obviousely you don't have a table with the name phpmyadmin.pma__table_uiprefs , give us a list of tables you have, some screenshots if it possible.